# how to get array of sequelize and mysql objects?

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays, object, sequelize.js

hello I have a nodejs project, I am using sequelize and mysql2 to access the database, in one of its routes I show an ejs view and I want to send a variable to it so that different products/cards are dynamically loaded from a form.
now when I use the findAll() method to call the different mysql records I try to bring an array of objects but it returns the loose objects so in the ejs view I cannot iterate with a foreach() for example

I execute this from a home route
i try this

```
 products_dataBase.findAll()
      .then(products => {
            products.forEach(element => {
            let result  = []
                result.push( element.dataValues) 
                res.render('home.ejs', { result });
                console.log(result)
            });
         })
        .catch(err => {
             console.log(err)
         })
```

```
[
  {
    id: 14,
    title: 'asdasd',
    price: 33434,
    description: 'sdasd',
    createdAt: 2022-11-08T02:06:12.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-11-08T02:06:12.000Z
  }
]
[
  {
    id: 15,
    title: 'asodfsd',
    price: 232,
    description: 'asdasd',
    createdAt: 2022-11-08T03:17:20.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-11-08T03:17:20.000Z
  }
]
[
  {
    id: 16,
    title: 'ldfsksdf',
    price: 343434,
    description: 'efsddsff',
    createdAt: 2022-11-08T03:17:44.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2022-11-08T03:17:44.000Z
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res.render` must be executed only once per request, but you invoke it repeatedly, in a `forEach` loop. Try this:

```js
products_dataBase.findAll()
.then(products => {
  let result = [];
  products.forEach(element => {
    result.push(element.dataValues);
  });
  res.render('home.ejs', { result });
  console.log(result);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: thanks, I was stupid, I'm a beginner